# Check for duplicates in a randomly generated list and replace them

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am making a minesweeper game with randomly generated bombs. Yet at times I have found that there are duplicates in my list of coordinates of bombs. How do I check for duplicates in a list and replace them with other randomised coordinates.

```
from random import randint

def create_bombpos():
    global BOMBS, NUM_BOMBS, GRID_TILES
    for i in range(0, NUM_BOMBS):
        x = randint(1, GRID_TILES)
        y = randint(1, GRID_TILES)
        BOMBS.append((x, y))
    print(BOMBS)
```

The user can decide how big the board is by input of `GRID_TILES`.
If they input 5, the board will be 5x5. The ammount of bombs is:

```
GRID_TILES * GRIDTILES / 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from random import randint

def create_bombpos():
    global BOMBS, NUM_BOMBS, GRID_TILES
    i = 0
    while i<NUM_BOMBS:
       x = randint(1, GRID_TILES)
       y = randint(1, GRID_TILES)
       if (x,y) not in BOMBS
           BOMBS.append((x, y))
           i = i + 1
    print(BOMBS)
```

If the newly generated point is already in the list, then `i` won't get incremented, and we will find another newly generated point, till it is not present in `BOMBS`.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thank you, this seems to help! I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 4):

Searching each time through your whole BOMBS list would cost you `O(n)` (linear time). Why don't you use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) instead? a Set guarantees that you ll end up with distinct (in terms of hashing) elements.

```
from random import randint

def create_bombpos():
BOMBS = set()
i = 0
while i<NUM_BOMBS:
   x = randint(1, GRID_TILES)
   y = randint(1, GRID_TILES)
   if (x,y) not in BOMBS
       BOMBS.add((x, y))
       i = i + 1
print(BOMBS)
```

Let me give u an example of a set:

```
>>> a = set()
>>> a.add((1,2))
>>> a
{(1, 2)}
>>> a.add((1,2))
>>> a.add((1,3))
>>> a.add((1,2))
>>> a
{(1, 2), (1, 3)}
```

I can add the same element to a set many times, but only 1 instance will be present.

Comment: Why do check if (x,y) is in BOMBS if you use a set?

Comment: Good catch @maximilianPeters. Left out of copy n paste.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that he does not care about the running time :)

Comment: Well, I guess even for 99 bombs running time will be negligible.

Comment: This looks like it'll attempt to add NUM_BOMBS but if there are any duplicates you will end up with fewer.

Comment: @sh1 you are right. Funny thing is that this was my original answer, but I thought that we didn't have to check for tuple existence given that we are working with a set. It seems that there's a good reason for that. I reverted it to my original answer. Thanks!

Comment: I used a similar device in C++ a while back, and I think that the `add` operation had a return type that would tell me whether or not I'd added a _new_ entry.  Perhaps it's the same here?  If you increment only when the add is successful then you only need to test for presence once (within `add`).

Comment: No i m afraid that set().add does not return something on python. But I wouldn't consider as an issue checking for existence more than once. Both checking for existence and adding a new element to a set are supposed to cost practically `O(1)` (constant) time

Answer (score 3):

You could also use random.sample to achieve this:

```
from random import sample

GRID_TILES = 100
NUM_BOMBS = 5

indexes = sample(range(GRID_TILES * GRID_TILES), NUM_BOMBS)
BOMBS = [(i // GRID_TILES, i % GRID_TILES) for i in indexes]
```

Comment: Best solution IMHO, can be even shortened to one line. No checks if the location exists because sample makes sure that every position is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use a python set for this, it will automatically check for duplicates and simply ignore every entry that already is in the list.
I also think the runtime is much better than using a list and checking for duplicates manually.

Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html